# WiFi is not working HPProbook4420s

Tags: wireless-networking

I have here a laptop (HP Probook 4420s) whose wifi button is not working. When I open <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> the button of Wifi is greyed out meaning  I cannot use wifi. I have no Idea how this happened. This used to work (said my aunt)(gave it to me). When this wifi didn't work reinstalled Windows 7* still did not fixed it. Please help me.

I didnt buy the device. This is from my aunt. In connection I have not much experience in this device..

Is there anyway I can turn the Wifi on?

Comment: (Add Information) No I don't see such yellow triangle with exclamation signs in my device manager.

Comment: [1]:http://www.ralinktech.com/license_us.php?n=1&p=1&t=U0wyRnpjMlYwY3k4eU1ERXhMekF4THpJeEwyUnZkMjVzYjJGa056VTROVFE0TWpnME1DNWxlR1U5UFQxSlUxOUJVRjlUVkVGZlVsUXlPRFl3WDBRdE15NHhMakUwTGpCZlZrRXRNeTR4TGpFMExqQmZWemN0TXk0eExqRTBMakJmVWxVdE5DNHdMalF1TUY5QlZTMDBMakF1TkM0d1h6QXhNVGd4TVY4eExqVXVNVEV1TUZkUVgwWnlaV1U9Qw%3D%3D  try installing the proper driver [here][1] this may be it from what ive gathered. Uninstall the HP driver that Windows 7 probably installed.

Comment: Hi NetworkKingPin thanks but I cant understand this (sorry) not a computer geek, would you elaborate please ? thanks !

from your comment : "the proper drivere [here][1]" I don't know where the link is. I know how to install too.

Comment: Hi networkkingpin, thanks.. when i Opened the link there are so much sublinks. which ? and also does this drivers match with my laptop model ?

Comment: Yes let me check home and I will give you the proper instructions

Comment: Try to update your pc. Mabey this will work

Comment: @luis when I was up to date before still the WiFi is not working.

Comment: @Already up to date. still no result

Comment: HELP ME I'M BEGGING D':

Comment: HELP PLEASE DON't JUST READ IT PLEASE HELP ME :((

Comment: OK so I would like to close this thread, for my problem is already solved. I don't know how this happened either. :/ 

Staff please close the thread :)